# Do hares chew cud?

Tags: physiology, zoology, bible, religious-texts

In Leviticus 11:6, a hare is referred to as a "chewer of the cud." What evidence is there on this matter?

It is not necessary, strictly speaking, that the evidence be on chewing cud in the same sense as ruminants. From my research, hares are not ruminants and do not possess the proper physiology. However, I am interested in any references or pieces of evidence for behavior that could be *perceived* as chewing cud.

Comment: As you know, we can only address claims which are notable. Can you provide examples of people actually believing this?

Comment: @Sklivvz: Here's a reference for notability, but it contains substantial parts of the answer in it, making it less suitable. http://creation.com/do-rabbits-chew-their-cud

Comment: Rabbits chew.  They chew a lot.  They will chew pretty much anything you put in front of them.  But they prefer grass and twigs.

Comment: @Coomie: there is a StackExchange site called Hermeneutics for people who find such discussions fulfilling.

Comment: @Coomie: I understand. You may well be right. But as soon as the discussion turns to what the authors/translators of the Bible really meant, the conversation goes down a rabbit hole the size of a camel.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Camel sized rabbits... now that would be an interesting breed :)

Comment: @Chad: They [existed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuralagus_rex)... well for small values of camel-sized.

Comment: @Chad: Rabbits chew because their [teeth keep growing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagomorph#Characteristics).

Comment: @MarkHurd - They chew for more reasons than that.  They chew because they are bored, and because they are anxious, and because they want out of their cage, and because it is night(or day).  I have heard it compared to rabbit version of twiddling their thumbs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you are willing for the definition of "chewing cud" to be very broad, then [caecotrophy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caecotrophy) may count.

Rabbit/hares excrete special pellets from the anus (different to regular faeces), which are reswallowed and redigested.

> Night feces (cecotropes) from this cecal fermented material are packaged in mucin 
>   and pass through the colon to the anus. These cecotropes are ingested by the rabbit and swallowed intact 
>   where they contribute substantially to the protein, mineral and vitamin nutriture of the animal.

- [Harrison Pet](http://www.harrisonpet.com/index.php?p=download&file=38) - not a particularly strong reference, but I don't think the science is in doubt here.

In the sense that the food is passed through the mouth twice for further digestion, it has some similarities to chewing the cud.

Comment: I'd suggest thst the willingness of OP to accept the broad definition is less critical than that of the translators of Leviticus. But since they're dead, is thrre evidence or logic to suggest they might've meant something more than pure ruminence? (or for that matter that we have "hares" exactly right in translation.)

Comment: @kojiro: While [this](http://creation.com/do-rabbits-chew-their-cud) and [this](http://www.sheaves.org/sheavings/hermeneutics.html) make the claim, I think this is off-topic. Interpretation of the bible belongs in Hermeneutics.SE, not Skeptics.SE.